# Power Automate Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, power-automate, powerapp

Currently working on a workflow to alert a user when certain expiration dates in a SharePoint list inside 6 different columns reach an expiration point.I created a SharePoint column to be used as a counter column that the flow updates everyday with today's date. The idea is to create a condition where the flow compare dates and based on today's date determine if that certification in the column is expired. Each of the certs expired 365 days after the user take it which means the flow needs to add 365 days to the dates in the columns and then compare this dates using multiple if statements to the counter column that marks today's date. Once the condition is met the flow should email an email to the user saying " your cert is expired ".

The problem is that from my standpoint to achieve this I will need to initialize 6 variables to create and store the expiration date of the certs (actual date in the column + 365 days) but when I do this the flow puts the variables in loops making it impossible to create the 6 variables because if so I would have 6 loops (one per variable), my idea was to initialize the variables with the actual value in the column and then "set the value" of the variable to val + 365 but it was also impossible because it gets the set variable parameter inside a loop as well, could someone help! [image] [image][image]

Comment: You don't need to create multiple variables in flow. You can add days to date column using expression & compare with today's date in "Condition" action. Here's reference to date & time functions in flow: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap I created the calculated column to compare with a counter column and that saves me the trouble of creating variales but when the flow gets to the if statement part to compare 2 different dates it returns with nothing, I wonder if its not reading the dates in the columns.

Comment: If you are comparing date columns with calculated date columns, first you have to convert them in same date-time format using [formatDateTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatdatetime), then you can compare them in "Condition" action.